# Undefined Property - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I try to activate to the registered user's account.

In order to that first create a model

```
function uyeOnay($registrationCode) {
    $query = "SELECT id FROM pasaj_register where activationCode = '" . $registrationCode . "'";
    $result = $this->db->query($query, $registrationCode);

    if ($result->num_rows() == 1) {
        $query = "UPDATE pasaj_register SET activated = 1 WHERE activationCode = ?";
        $this->query->query($query, $registrationCode);

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

then  i called it in my controller

```
public function kayitEmailOnay() {

        $registrationCode = $this->uri->segment(3);

        if ($registrationCode == '') {
            echo "URLde onay kodu yok";
        }


        $registrationConfirmed = $this->kayitmodel->uyeOnay($registrationCode);

        if ($registrationConfirmed)
            echo "successful";
        else
            echo "unsuccessful";
    }
```

i also called my model in constructor

```
public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('kayitmodel');
    }
```

However, i get this error ,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i think that (in `uyeOnay` function) :

```
$this->query->query($query, $registrationCode);
```

need to be :

```
$this->db->query($query, $registrationCode);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->query->query($query, $registrationCode);
```

Should be

```
$this->db->query($query, $registrationCode);
```